# Gamma Distribution and Probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The lifetimes of batteries are independent exponential random variables, each having parameter λ. A flashlight needs 2 batteries to work. If one has a flashlight and a stockpile of n batteries, what is the distribution of time that the flashlight can operate?

My friend said this was a gamma distribution with parameters (n/2, λ). But what does that even mean? I honestly have no idea where to begin. I know the distribution for an exponential random variable, $λe^{-λx}$, but other than that, not much. Help

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent $\mathrm{Exp}(\lambda)$ random variables, then for any $t>0$,
$$\mathbb P(X\wedge Y>t) = \mathbb P(X>t, Y>t) = \mathbb P(X>t)\mathbb P(Y>t)=e^{-2\lambda t}, $$
so $X\wedge Y$ has $\mathrm{Exp}(2\lambda)$ distribution (here $\wedge$ denotes $\min$). The time until the flashlight needs a replacement battery has this distribution.

Since the flashlight requires two batteries, and one battery at a time fails, from the memoryless property of the exponential distribution, the total lifetime of the flashlight is the sum of $n-1$ $\mathrm{Exp}(2\lambda)$ random variables, i.e. follows the gamma distribution with parameters $n-1$ and $2\lambda$. The probability density would be

$$f(t) = \frac{(2\lambda)^{n-1}}{(n-2)!}t^{n-2}e^{-2\lambda t}, \quad t>0. $$

Comment: what would the notation of that be. My book uses lots of notation and I cant translate that into math on my own.

Answer (score 1):

The exponential distribution is often used as a model for the waiting time until failure of a part.  If you replace the part with a new part with it fails, which has the same exponential distribution and fails independently of the first part, then the waiting time until failure of the two parts in succession is not exponentially distributed -- it is a sum of two independent identically distributed exponential variables.  Similarly, the waiting time until the failure of $n$ parts in succession is a sum of $n$ exponential variables.  The sum of $n$ such variables has a distribution function known as a gamma distribution.

The gamma distribution is determined by two parameters. In the most general case, these parameters can be positive real numbers, but then the density function for the gamma distribution is hard to describe.  In the case of successive waiting times, the first parameter $n$ is a positive whole number, and the density function is easier to describe: the gamma density function with parameters $n$ and $\lambda$ is

$\frac{\lambda^n}{(n-1)!} x^{n-1} e^{-\lambda x}, \quad x>0$

Note that when $n=1$, this is exactly the exponential density function you gave.  It is good to check consider the case $n=2$ to begin to understand the gamma density.  You should be able to check in that case, using integration by parts, that the integral of the density function is $1$.

Now if the time to expiration of a given pair of batteries was exponentially distributed with mean time to failure $1/\lambda$, then your friend would be right (in the case $n$ is even).  But because you will take out a dead battery and replace it while the other one is left in, this example is not gamma distributed with parameters $n/2$ and $\lambda$.

Comment: so if we took the integral of what you wrote we would have the distribution?

Comment: If you integrate a probability density function from $-\infty$ to $T$, it gives the value of the cumulative distribution function at $T$.

Comment: which is what we want correct?

Comment: "distribution" isn't necessarily the same as "cumulative distribution function".  A distribution generally is just some method of assigning probabilities to outcomes.  When I say that the time to failure of a battery is often modeled as an exponential distribution, that is describing the general method of assigning probabilities to the possible time intervals during which the battery might fail.

Comment: okay. So then what you have is just the distribution then, which is what the question asks for

Comment: The correct answer is the one given by Math1000 in his answer -- Gamma with parameters $n-1$ and $2\lambda$.  The reason, though, is rather sophisticated, as you can see from his answer.  You must understand the memoryless property of exponential variables and how to calculate the density function of the minimum of two variables.  The phrasing of your question made it sound like we should probably not assume that level of background knowledge, so I attempted to explain instead just what a gamma distribution is.  And also what your friend was thinking when he produced his incorrect answer.